# Google Reader API Unread Count

Tags: api, google-reader

Does Google Reader have an API and if so, how can I get the count of the number of unread posts for a specific user knowing their username and password?

Comment: @GateKiller: I understand the motivation for throwing a "code-request" tag onto this... I also have an open bounty on a question where the only answer is a link to the (broken) API documentation, and it irritates me that i'll end up paying out 300 rep to someone who just Googled my keywords.

Comment: But, the tag doesn't serve any purpose. Rather, you should add a note to your actual question stating you'd appreciate sample code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This URL will give you a count of unread posts per feed.  You can then iterate over the feeds and sum up the counts.

http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?all=true

Here is a minimalist example in Python...parsing the xml/json and summing the counts is left as an exercise for the reader:

```py
import urllib
import urllib2

username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = '******'

# Authenticate to obtain SID
auth_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin'
auth_req_data = urllib.urlencode({'Email': username,
                                  'Passwd': password,
                                  'service': 'reader'})
auth_req = urllib2.Request(auth_url, data=auth_req_data)
auth_resp = urllib2.urlopen(auth_req)
auth_resp_content = auth_resp.read()
auth_resp_dict = dict(x.split('=') for x in auth_resp_content.split('\n') if x)
auth_token = auth_resp_dict["Auth"]

# Create a cookie in the header using the SID 
header = {}
header['Authorization'] = 'GoogleLogin auth=%s' % auth_token

reader_base_url = 'http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?%s'
reader_req_data = urllib.urlencode({'all': 'true',
                                    'output': 'xml'})
reader_url = reader_base_url % (reader_req_data)
reader_req = urllib2.Request(reader_url, None, header)
reader_resp = urllib2.urlopen(reader_req)
reader_resp_content = reader_resp.read()

print reader_resp_content
```

And some additional links on the topic:

- http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI
- [How do you access an authenticated Google App Engine service from a (non-web) python client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101742/how-do-you-access-an-authenticated-google-app-engine-service-from-a-non-web-pyt)
- http://blog.gpowered.net/2007/08/google-reader-api-functions.html

Comment: For general interst - since the changes made to Google Reader API in june, this example no longer works...

Comment: Fixed this example.  Thanks to livibetter -- I had read up on the SID -> Auth change, but didn't see the 'service': 'reader' part documented anywhere.

Comment: Great! It is also important for people to start this ticket on Google Api's tracker, so that Google stop locking people into greader: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=29&sort=-stars&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Answer (score 11):

It is [there](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI). Still in Beta though.

Comment: This question answers the question as it is asked. If there is some reason why the question author does not find it sufficient, perhaps he should edit his question to clarify.

Comment: As much as I would like it, this is NOT an official Google Reader api. It is merely reverse-engineered guess that can break at any moment.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an update to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880/google-reader-api-unread-count/582108#582108)

```
import urllib
import urllib2

username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = '******'

# Authenticate to obtain Auth
auth_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin'
#auth_req_data = urllib.urlencode({'Email': username,
#                                  'Passwd': password})
auth_req_data = urllib.urlencode({'Email': username,
                                  'Passwd': password,
                                  'service': 'reader'})
auth_req = urllib2.Request(auth_url, data=auth_req_data)
auth_resp = urllib2.urlopen(auth_req)
auth_resp_content = auth_resp.read()
auth_resp_dict = dict(x.split('=') for x in auth_resp_content.split('\n') if x)
# SID = auth_resp_dict["SID"]
AUTH = auth_resp_dict["Auth"]

# Create a cookie in the header using the Auth
header = {}
#header['Cookie'] = 'Name=SID;SID=%s;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=160000000000' % SID
header['Authorization'] = 'GoogleLogin auth=%s' % AUTH

reader_base_url = 'http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?%s'
reader_req_data = urllib.urlencode({'all': 'true',
                                    'output': 'xml'})
reader_url = reader_base_url % (reader_req_data)
reader_req = urllib2.Request(reader_url, None, header)
reader_resp = urllib2.urlopen(reader_req)
reader_resp_content = reader_resp.read()

print reader_resp_content
```

Google Reader removed SID auth around June, 2010 (I think), using new Auth from ClientLogin is the new way and it's a bit simpler (header is shorter). You will have to add `service` in data for requesting `Auth`, I noticed no `Auth` returned if you don't send the `service=reader`.

You can read more about the change of authentication method in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/fougrapi/browse_thread/thread/e331f37f7f126c00/).

Answer (score 0):

In the API posted in [1], the "token" field should be "T"

[1] http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI

Comment: This is not a scientific article. You can place links [1] inline! :-)

Comment: @drozzy I am working under the assumption you are not joking. All Yassin did was miss a colon. A colon directly after the second [1] fits the markdown syntax and makes it an inline link. This can be quicker, no mouse clicks needed, then using the provided gui interface.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what got into me.