# How do you access an authenticated Google App Engine service from a (non-web) python client?

Tags: python, web-services, google-app-engine, authentication

I have a Google App Engine app - http://mylovelyapp.appspot.com/
It has a page - mylovelypage

For the moment, the page just does `self.response.out.write('OK')`

If I run the following Python at my computer:

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://mylovelyapp.appspot.com/mylovelypage")
s = f.read()
print s
f.close()
```

it prints "OK"

the problem is if I add `login:required` to this page in the app's yaml

then this prints out the HTML of the Google Accounts login page

I've tried "normal" authentication approaches. e.g.

```
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(None,
                          uri='http://mylovelyapp.appspot.com/mylovelypage',
                          user='billy.bob@gmail.com',
                          passwd='billybobspasswd')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

But it makes no difference - I still get the login page's HTML back.

I've tried [Google's ClientLogin auth API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html), but I can't get it to work.

```
h = httplib2.Http()

auth_uri = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
myrequest = "Email=%s&Passwd=%s&service=ah&source=DALELANE-0.0" % ("billy.bob@gmail.com", "billybobspassword")
response, content = h.request(auth_uri, 'POST', body=myrequest, headers=headers)

if response['status'] == '200':
    authtok = re.search('Auth=(\S*)', content).group(1)

    headers = {}
    headers['Authorization'] = 'GoogleLogin auth=%s' % authtok.strip()
    headers['Content-Length'] = '0'

    response, content = h.request("http://mylovelyapp.appspot.com/mylovelypage", 
                                  'POST', 
                                  body="", 
                                  headers=headers)

    while response['status'] == "302":        
        response, content = h.request(response['location'], 'POST', body="", headers=headers) 

    print content
```

I do seem to be able to get some token correctly, but attempts to use it in the header when I call 'mylovelypage' still just return me the login page's HTML. :-(

Can anyone help, please?

Could I use the [GData client library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) to do this sort of thing? From
what I've read, I think it should be able to access App Engine apps,
but I haven't been any more successful at getting the authentication working for App Engine stuff there either

Any pointers to samples, articles, or even just keywords I should be
searching for to get me started, would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

appcfg.py, the tool that uploads data to App Engine has to do exactly this to authenticate itself with the App Engine server. The relevant functionality is abstracted into appengine_rpc.py. In a nutshell, the solution is:

1. Use the [Google ClientLogin API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html) to obtain an authentication token. appengine_rpc.py does this in [_GetAuthToken](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py#180)
2. Send the auth token to a special URL on your App Engine app. That page then returns a cookie and a 302 redirect. Ignore the redirect and store the cookie. appcfg.py does this in [_GetAuthCookie](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py#228)
3. Use the returned cookie in all future requests.

You may also want to look at [_Authenticate](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py#253), to see how appcfg handles the various return codes from ClientLogin, and [_GetOpener](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py#397), to see how appcfg creates a urllib2 OpenerDirector that doesn't follow HTTP redirects. Or you could, in fact, just use the AbstractRpcServer and HttpRpcServer classes wholesale, since they do pretty much everything you need.

Comment: I'd got as far as getting an authtoken, but hadn't tried using it to get a cookie - thanks very much for the pointer!

Comment: I've included the source in a new 'answer' below - thanks again

Comment: Links are broken ("_GetAuthToken", "_GetAuhtcookie", etc.)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps says that ClientLogin is deprecated as of April 2012.  Is there an Oauth2 equivalent for this?

Answer (score 34):

thanks to Arachnid for the answer - it worked as suggested

here is a simplified copy of the code, in case it is helpful to the next person to try!

```
import os
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

users_email_address = "billy.bob@gmail.com"
users_password      = "billybobspassword"

target_authenticated_google_app_engine_uri = 'http://mylovelyapp.appspot.com/mylovelypage'
my_app_name = "yay-1.0"



# we use a cookie to authenticate with Google App Engine
#  by registering a cookie handler here, this will automatically store the 
#  cookie returned when we use urllib2 to open http://currentcost.appspot.com/_ah/login
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

#
# get an AuthToken from Google accounts
#
auth_uri = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin'
authreq_data = urllib.urlencode({ "Email":   users_email_address,
                                  "Passwd":  users_password,
                                  "service": "ah",
                                  "source":  my_app_name,
                                  "accountType": "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE" })
auth_req = urllib2.Request(auth_uri, data=authreq_data)
auth_resp = urllib2.urlopen(auth_req)
auth_resp_body = auth_resp.read()
# auth response includes several fields - we're interested in 
#  the bit after Auth= 
auth_resp_dict = dict(x.split("=")
                      for x in auth_resp_body.split("\n") if x)
authtoken = auth_resp_dict["Auth"]

#
# get a cookie
# 
#  the call to request a cookie will also automatically redirect us to the page
#   that we want to go to
#  the cookie jar will automatically provide the cookie when we reach the 
#   redirected location

# this is where I actually want to go to
serv_uri = target_authenticated_google_app_engine_uri

serv_args = {}
serv_args['continue'] = serv_uri
serv_args['auth']     = authtoken

full_serv_uri = "http://mylovelyapp.appspot.com/_ah/login?%s" % (urllib.urlencode(serv_args))

serv_req = urllib2.Request(full_serv_uri)
serv_resp = urllib2.urlopen(serv_req)
serv_resp_body = serv_resp.read()

# serv_resp_body should contain the contents of the 
#  target_authenticated_google_app_engine_uri page - as we will have been 
#  redirected to that page automatically 
#
# to prove this, I'm just gonna print it out
print serv_resp_body
```

Comment: What about in the dev environment?

Comment: That is, when you wish to authenticate locally instead of from https://www.google.com/accounts

Comment: To authenticate locally, you just supply a simple cookie with the desired username. Sniff a request to see exactly what it is. :)

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: This answer has become obsolete: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps

Answer (score 1):

for those who can't get ClientLogin to work, try app engine's [OAuth support](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Im not too familiar with AppEngine, or Googles web apis, but for a brute force approach you could write a script with something like mechanize (http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to simply walk through the login process before you begin doing the real work of the client.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a python expert or a app engine expert. But did you try following the sample appl at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/gettingstarted/usingusers.html. I created one at http://quizengine.appspot.com, it seemed to work fine with Google authentication and everything.
Just a suggestion, but look in to the getting started guide. Take it easy if the suggestion sounds naive. :)
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, the problem isn't authenticating in an App Engine app. As you say - that is straightforward. 

The problem is accessing the app engine from a Python code running on my desktop computer. Getting into the authenticated Google ecosystem from here is what I'm stuck on.