# How to make an authenticated request from a script to appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do I make an authenticated request from a python script to appengine? I have found lots of different methods on the web but none work.
E.G. [How do you access an authenticated Google App Engine service from a (non-web) python client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101742/how-do-you-access-an-authenticated-google-app-engine-service-from-a-non-web-py) doesn't work, the request returns the login page.
That post is old, maybe something changed since then.
Has anyone got a nice wrapped object to do this?

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question:

```
from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc
use_production = True
if use_production:
  base_url = 'myapp.appspot.com'
else:
  base_url = 'localhost:8080'


def passwdFunc():
  return ('user@gmail.com','password')

def main(argv):
  rpcServer = appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer(base_url,
                                          passwdFunc,
                                          None,
                                          'myapp',
                                          save_cookies=True,
                                          secure=use_production)
# Makes the actual call, I guess is the same for POST and GET?
blah = rpcServer.Send('/some_path/')

print blah

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Is this the only way? can't you just authenticate by making a request to the login url?

Comment: This no longer works, as appengine_rpc uses ClientLogin, which has been deprecated and removed (see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps)

Answer (score 0):

You can see one example of a non-web authenticated python client making requests in the Python client library used to process GAE Pull Queues at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull#Using_the_Task_Queue_REST_API_with_the_Python_Google_API_Library