# email out useage report

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I set up APP ENGINE to email out to management the daily usage report.

I have billing working and the daily report would be a start
I have included Appstats but there is no option to email out a report.

I am open to ideas

Answer (score 0):

If you go to you GAE admin billing history page, there is now a "Download Usage Reports (CSV) " link. This link has url `https://appengine.google.com/billing/history.csv?app_id=s%7Eyour-app-id`. This will give you billing data in CSV format.

However, this requires caller to have admin privileges in order to call it. You can achieve this programmatically in two ways:

1. `Clientlogin` access (which is being deprecated, but `appcfg` still uses it). See first answer: [How do you access an authenticated Google App Engine service from a (non-web) python client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101742/how-do-you-access-an-authenticated-google-app-engine-service-from-a-non-web-py)
2. The new [OAuth2 auth for Web apps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServerhttp://). You will have to declare `offline` access, then for the first time you should do the login manually and then store token for offline use. Also, to access GAE, you will need to declare scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin`.