# parse xml feed using python feedparser

Tags: python

i have this feed which i would like to pull the info out of http://www.boutique-artisans-du-monde.com/rss/catalog/category/cid/6/store_id/1/

from the code i have

```
try:
   xml = urllib2.urlopen(link_rss)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
   pass
else:
   f = feedparser.parse(xml)
   print len(f.entries)
```

when i print the len(f.entries) maximum entries i get is 50 what is the correct way to pull all the entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it returns all the entries, maybe that's only what the feed contains. If you want to pull older entries you will have to find the correct feed and pass it to the `feedparser` RSS is just an XML file stored at the server.

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676258/1157444)

Comment: Yep, the feed only contains 50 items

Comment: @Dikei I guess this answers your question :)

Comment: It's not my question though :)

Comment: @Dikei sorry, confused you for the OP :)