# Pagination using feedparser python

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

how to get old post of rss blog feed using feedparser module in python?

```
import feedparser
content = feedparser.parse('http://blog.itiffin.in/index.php/feed/')
print len(content['items']) # gives 10. But there are lot of old blogs feeds there.
```

How to fetch old entries using feedparser in python?

Comment: The xml you reference at http://blog.itiffin.in/index.php/feed/ has only 10 items in it...
I'd suggest trying a source that has more than 10 items ...

Comment: You mean `feedparser.parse`.

Comment: Look the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676223/feedparser-retrieve-old-messages-from-google-reader.