# Using Python to get Substack posts without scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rss, feedparser

I want to create a dataframe of Substack posts from all the newsletter I subscribe to. But using `feedparser` + Substack's RSS feeds only seem to go back ~20 posts—even if a particular newsletter has hundreds of old posts.

Is there a way to use RSS to get all the old posts too? Or another method to get the same data I can using the RSS feed that *doesn't* involve scraping/`beautifulSoup`?

```
import feedparser
import pandas as pd

rawrss = ['https://heathercoxrichardson.substack.com/feed', 'https://marcstein.substack.com/feed']

posts = []
for url in rawrss:
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    for post in feed.entries:
        posts.append((post.title, post.link, post.summary, post.summary_detail, post.content, post.published))
df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['title', 'link', 'summary', 'summary_detail', 'content', 'published'])
print(df)
```

Comment: I've never used feedparser but take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676223/feedparser-retrieve-old-messages-from-google-reader . According to it the RSS feeds you're looking at aren't storing more historical data?

Answer (score 3):

There's an unofficial Substack API available for that. Here's a curl request that fetches the second page of the most recent posts:

```
curl https://ava.substack.com/api/v1/posts\?limit\=50\&offset\=50
```

Note that this is unofficial API so this can change at any time.