# get Unread Count of Google Reader using Javascript(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-reader

i'm trying to get the unread count of my google reader using javascript.

tried the following:

```
var unreadURL   = "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?all=true";

$.ajax({
    url: unreadURL,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

but im getting a 401. i think i have to authenticate or something, but i have no idea how to do this.

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880/google-reader-api-unread-count) topic, and they are first authenticating using another page, and then setting a cookie (if i read this python right), but i'm not familiar with python and don't know what to do in javascript.

any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in stating that you need to authenticate to use the service.  However, for [security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) modern day browsers do not allow client-side code to make calls to third party sites. There are [ways](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) to get around this, but the typical approach to this problem is to make your requests to the third party site form the server-side then return the results to the client.

So, in your case you can make an Ajax call to server-side code running on your site. This code would then:

- Use the [Google ClientLogin API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html) to
  authenticate to the Google
- Get the unread-count
- Return the results to your
  client-side code (the result could
  also be in XML or JSON format)

Comment: poorly i can not, because i wanted to do this in an addon for safari. thanks for this information.