# Google Reader and Twitter: archive and use tweets with python script

Tags: python, twitter, archive, google-reader

i'd like to archive tweets from an hashtag in Twitter.
I'm using Google Reader and my subscription is something like search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23HASHTAG

But, when i'm trying to retrieve from google search cache with this link
www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23HASHTAG
the result is empty even if i have a lot of items in google reader web interface

What's wrong?

Second question: Does anyone know if it's possible to retrieve the cache archive in this subscription as describe [here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/06/reconstruct-feeds-history-using-google.html)? 
Can i use a script like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/582108) to read the result or there is a better one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you escape the feed URL correctly. Instead of http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23HASHTAG , you'll need to use http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://search.twitter.com/search.atom%3Fq=%23HASHTAG (`?` escaped as a `%3F`).

Note that Google Reader will only have an archive of a feed if one or more Reader users have subscribed to that feed.